# Google Reports API Push Notifications

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I have been running an implementation for push notifications so I can be notified when a user logs in. It was working good but then it stopped working approximately two weeks ago. Here's the logic in my module.

```
com.google.api.services.admin.reports.model.Channel
rchannel = new com.google.api.services.admin.reports.model.Channel()
.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
.setType("web_hook")
.setAddress("https://www.example.com/entry-point/gapi-reports");

//Create an array of all available activity for audit
List<String> applicationNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
//applicationNameList.add("admin");
//applicationNameList.add("calendar");
//applicationNameList.add("drive");
applicationNameList.add("login");
//applicationNameList.add("token");

for (String applicationName: applicationNameList) {
  reports.activities().watch("all", applicationName,rchannel).execute();
  System.out.println("Hello Successfully registered report service watch for user " + user.getPrimaryEmail() + "application name: " + applicationName);
}
```

Is there a way to list the subscription IDs for the push notifications that have been setup to confirm if a subscription is really active?
And if active, whether there are any errors during sending a push
notification response?

In general, is there a way to access Google logs for push notifications subscription requests and responses?

Comment: When you said it stopped working, what actually happened? Any error logs?

Comment: I mean.. I'm not able to get the push notifications anymore just for the logins report. I have no error logs. The push notifications are just not coming.